# How to solve the complex equation $z^4+z^2+1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the complex number equation of $$z^4+z^2+1=0$$
I know that if it were $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$, I know how to solve. But now I just don't know any method or lemma on how solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really curious how you know to solve $z^4+z^3+z^2+1=0$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami it was z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0. i edited my question. thank for your useful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Set $Z^2=y$ to get $y^2+y+1=0$ and $$(y-1)(y^2+y+1)=?$$

Alternatively, $$(Z^2)^2+Z^2+1=0\implies Z^2=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}2=e^{\pm2 i\pi/3}=e^{\pi i(2m\pm1)/3}$$ where $m$ is any integer

$$Z=e^{\pi i(2m\pm1)/6}$$ where $m=0,1$

Comment: Thank u. i got it. i forget that i can use that method. thanks a lot

Comment: @Nima, Welcome. Don't miss the alternative method as well'

Comment: yeah. by the way is it okay or is there any limitation in how many questions  can ask on stackexchange in each day? I'm studying a Bachelor of math, but im really weak in it and face with lots of problems :(

Comment: @Nima,I don't think so. But make sure that each question contains your efforts as well

Answer (score 3):

$$z^4+z^2+1=z^4+2z^2+1-z^2=(z^2+z+1)(z^2-z+1).$$

Now, solve two quadratic equations.

Answer (score 1):

Using $z^2=u$  solve the equation
$$
u^2+u+1=0
$$
that gives $u=-\frac{1}{2}(1\pm i\sqrt{3})$ so 
$$
z=\pm \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}(1\pm i\sqrt{3})}
$$